# Options for playing multicast video on a web page

Tags: flash, silverlight, video, html, multicast

Assuming a network hierarchy that supports video multicasting, what options are there today to tap into this stream from a web page?

I've seen some references to this with Silverlight and project Star Light, which I unfortunately have no experience with. It also feels like a third option behind HTML5 and Flash.

What is out there on the market today that can handle this?

Answer (score 1):

[Qumu](http://www.qumu.com/) offers Multicast video for Silverlight today.  Silverlight 4 (released in the first half of 2010) will have enhanced abilities for multicast as well.